# How to move generated source of gradle?

Tags: gradle, build

I'm starting to use gradle on my projects and I want to automatic install the file generated after build.

I tried to search, but didn't found.

How to move the .jar from build/libs to another paste, something like c:\server\plugins

I tried this code, but did't work

```
task deploy(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['build']) {
    from 'build/libs'
    into "c:/server/plugins/"
}
```

Here my build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/nwwdq0wd

Edit:

Did't work means the build file is not being copied/moved to where I want to

Comment: Define "doesn't work" precisely. What command are you executing, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead, precisely?

Comment: Did't work means the build file is not being copied/moved to where I want to

Comment: And what happened **instead**. And what command did you execute?

Comment: I did just gradle build

Comment: There is your problem. You launched the task `build` instead of launching the task `deploy`. `deploy` depends on `build`, so launching it will execute `build`, and then execute the copy defined in the `deploy` task.

Comment: I will try Jb, thank you for the help

Comment: Worked, thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the folowing command and worked. Thanks @JBNizet

```
gradle deploy
```